# What is the connector on CR1220 laptop batteries?

Tags: batteries, connector, laptop

I have an Asus Zenbook UX301L with a dead BIOS battery. I pulled the battery out and see that it's a CR1220 with spot welded wires and a white plastic connector. I am trying to find the specs of the connector. It's the same white connector pictured here:

[image]

What is this thing?

Comment: It can be any connector. You need to take measurements of the connector and describe it further to find a matching connector. For example, are the terminals round, square, or blade type?

Answer (score 1):

On [this e-bay page](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/334454499673) the connector details are given (Trust it at your own risk):

[image]

No part numbers are given, so it's really difficult to find an exact one. From [here](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors/rectangular-connector-housings/319?s=N4IgjCBcoBw1oDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbXACYwBmcgNhAF0CAHAFyhAGVWAnASwB2AcxABfAjACcCEMkjps%2BIqRC0YAFnhMQbDt37CxBMJKky5C3AWKQyABkainQA) you can check every single one and find the best match, if you want.

Remember that the list is for housings only, so you'll also need the crimps/terminals. If you pick the right housing, associated products (crimps, mating connectors, etc) will be shown at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of these:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - [125SH + 125CH](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/4/page_234-240-12264.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/hmrd0qqn)
- [Amphenol](https://www.amphenol-icc.com/product-series/125mm-wire-to-board.html/) - [101148](https://cdn.amphenol-icc.com/media/wysiwyg/files/documentation/datasheet/boardwiretoboard/bwb_1.25mm_wtb.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/20?keywords=101148&pkeyword=101148&keywords=&v=609)
- Harwin - [M30](https://cdn.harwin.com/pdfs/Harwin_PC_Connectors.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/2m4hmmnr)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/DF13) - [DF13 (1r 3w)](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=DF13&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D31687_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/bmb942z7)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/DF13) - [DF13 (1r 4w)](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=DF13&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D31687_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/9mqp9878)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/DF14) - [DF14](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=DF14&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D31686_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/mfdcp7jq)
- JAE - IL-Z - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/7rmm3fvd)
- Molex - Panelmate - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/z0d9mf)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/picoblade) - [PicoBlade (3w)](http://www.literature.molex.com/SQLImages/kelmscott/Molex/PDF_Images/987651-3691.PDF) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/20?k=PicoBlade)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/picoblade) - [PicoBlade (4w)](http://www.literature.molex.com/SQLImages/kelmscott/Molex/PDF_Images/987651-3691.PDF) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/20?k=PicoBlade)
- Sullins - [SWR120 + SWH120](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Sullins%20PDFs/SWR120-NPEG-Sxx-ST-BG.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/8m9rq18q)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/intersection/high-performance-interconnects.html?tab=pgp-story) - [HPI-1.25 (3w)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773713-2_HPI_QRG_EN&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/vjvjrwjd)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/intersection/high-performance-interconnects.html?tab=pgp-story) - [HPI-1.25 (4w)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773713-2_HPI_QRG_EN&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/hrddbmb7)
- [Wurth](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/em/connectors/wire-to-board/wr_wtb/wr_wtb_1_25_mm) - WR-WTB 653 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/wzp9mnvj)

(I used  my [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_1p2&fl=0000000010000000000000002000000000-508-%7C1.25%7C2%7C%7C%7C)).